# deleted_$taxonomy not getting fired

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hooks

Want to call a function after my custom taxonomy was deleted. But the hook is not getting fired.

Registered taxonomy on init hook callback

```
    register_taxonomy(
        'college-session',
        'collegesession',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'College Session','college-session' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'college-session' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
        )
    );
```

The hook is listed in [WP hook reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Taxonomy_and_Terms) page.

**deleted_$taxonomy**

Runs after a term in a specific taxonomy is deleted, and after the term cache has been cleaned.

Is this a known issue.? Does anyone have a solution/example.?

```
add_action('deleted_college-session', 'update_deleted_session_relations');

function update_deleted_session_relations($tt_id){

    // Do the action here

}
```

Comment: What's your code for registering the taxonomy? And what's the action you're trying to perform?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Question updated

Comment: I don't think that's a valid action, try `delete_$taxonomy`.

Comment: @Milo deleted_term_taxonomy (Since version 2.9.0) 
Runs after a term taxonomy ID is deleted.

Comment: I can't see any problem with your code so far, so the question is what makes you think the hook isn't running? What code are you attempting to run on the hook?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Just sending a mail or logging something to file....Any test case is not working. So I ended up like this hook is not triggering. I reported this on WP forum as well months back, but no response.

Comment: @MujeebuRahman search WordPress core code for this action and tell me where you find it. Also note that there are many errors in Codex, the [`register_taxonomy` page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) states that a hyphen is not valid in the name of a taxonomy, which is false.

Comment: @JacobPeattie can you upvote my question so it can get more attention

Comment: Might be forum mistake?